# Javascript Array Error on iOs: 'undefined is not an object'

Tags: javascript, ios, arrays, ipad, charat

I am working on a game where you navigate a labyrinth with text, selecting to go right, left, forward, or backward. It works fine on my browser (you can see it [here](http://www.koanoftheday.com/caves)), but it won't work on iPads and iPhones.

When I used the WebKit to debug the code in Safari on my iPad, it told me

> 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'map[yyou].charAt')

and it pointed to the fourth line of code here (the one that begins `if (xyou<24)`).

```
function checkSpace(xyou,yyou){
  if (yyou>0) blockcheck[0] = map[yyou-1].charAt(xyou);
  else blockcheck[0] = "1";
  if (xyou<24) blockcheck[1] = map[yyou].charAt(xyou+1);
  else blockcheck[1] = "1";
  if (yyou<21) blockcheck[2] = map[yyou+1].charAt(xyou);
  else blockcheck[2] = "1";
  if (xyou>0) blockcheck[3] = map[yyou].charAt(xyou-1);
  else blockcheck[3] = "1";
  doorBlock();
}
```

I am very new to Javascript, and an amateur at programming. So it's quite possible that it's something very simple. This is my first time to actually post a question on Stack Overflow, but it's been incredibly helpful for me in the past. Thanks to anyone who answers.

Comment: When using the debugger, what does `map` and `yyou` look like on the line that gives the error?

Comment: what is the length of your `map` variable and what is the value of your `yyou` variable, at the time you are getting the error. It is clear that when you are getting this error, the value of `yyou` is greater than length of `map` - 1. So `map[yyou]` is returning `undefined` and then you are trying to call `charAt` on `undefined`, its erring out cuz there is no such method.

Comment: yyou is 0, and `map[0]` is a string in the array set by `map[0] = "0000000100041000101011000";` so it shouldn't be undefined.

However, there is something to that, because when I change the starting coordinates, there isn't a problem.

I want to reiterate that this problem does not occur on Chrome or Safari on my laptop. They have no problem. Only on my iPhone and iPad. Are there any known issues which might cause such a discrepancy? Something with the zeroeth line of the array?

Perhaps I should just shift the map so that there is a wall at `map[0]`, but I'd rather know what was wrong.